# Django - How to filter children of a nested queryset?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this model called Menu which has a many-to-many relationship with another model called category. Both this models have a field called is_active which indicates that menu or category is available or not.
Alright, then I have an api called RestaurantMenus, which returns all active menus for a restaurant with their categories extended, the response is something like this:

```
Menu 1
     Category 1
     Category 2
Menu 2
     Category 3
Menu 3
     Category 4
     Category 5
     Category 6
```

Now what I try to achieve is to only seriliaze those menus and categories which are active (is_active = True). To filter active menus is simple but to filter its children is what I'm struggling with.

My Models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, related_name='categories', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Menu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

My Serializers:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = "__all__"

class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categories = CategorySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = "__all__"
```

P.S. Category model itself has a many-to-many relationship with another model Called Item, which has an is_active field too. I want the same effect for those too but I cut it from the question cause I think the process should be the same. So actually the api response is something like this:

```
Menu 1
     Category 1
          Item 1
          Item 2
          Item 3
     Category 2
          Item 4
```

Comment: Please add your model and serializer codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can use Django [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) objects. This lets you define queryset to choose the set objects from.

So, you would write your `Menu` retrieval query something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

menus = Menu.objects.filter(is_active=True).prefetch_related(Prefetch('categories', queryset=Category.objects.filter(is_active=True)))
```

To add category items as well to the result set, use the following query:

```
menus = Menu.objects.filter(is_active=True).prefetch_related(Prefetch('categories', queryset=Category.objects.filter(is_active=True)), Prefetch('categories__items', queryset=Item.objects.filter(is_active=True))))
```

This should solve your problem.

**Note**: I have not tested the code so you might need to make some modifications.

Comment: @VahidAl Always happy to help :)

Answer (score 3):

Using a `SerializerMethodField` is pretty straightforward.

You can filter inside **get_< attribute >**, you serialize the queryset and return the data from this serialized queryset.

```py
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = "__all__"

class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categories = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_categories')

    def get_categories(self, menu):
        qs = Category.objects.filter(menu=menu, is_active=True)
        serializer = CategorySerializer(qs, many=True)
        return serializer.data
    
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = "__all__"
```

If you have a third nested class, you can just apply the same simple logic to `CategorySerializer` using a `get_items` and `ItemSerializer`.

This approach lets you filter Menu objects to check `is_active = True` on your views.py since this is business logic.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you define your models like this

```
Menu
    is_active
    categories: ManyToManyField (related_name='menus')

Category
    is_active
    items: ManyToManyField (related_name='categories')

Item
    is_active
```

E.g.

```
def get_categories():
    active_category_qs = Category.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    active_menu_qs = Menu.objects.filter(is_active=True, 
    categories__in=active_category_qs)
    categories = []

    for menu in active_menu_qs.iterator():
        for category in menu.categories.all():
            if category.id not in [
                    obj_target["id"] for obj_target in categories
            ]:
                category_data = CategorySerializer(category).data # just get the data of category object
                categories.append(category_data)
    return categories
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this using [`list_serializer_class`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-behavior):

```
class FilterActiveListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        data = data.filter(is_active=True)
        return super(FilterActiveListSerializer, self).to_representation(data)

class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        list_serializer_class = FilterActiveListSerializer

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = ItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        list_serializer_class = FilterActiveListSerializer 

class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categories = CategorySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model  = Category
        fields = "__all__"

class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category     = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_category(self,instance):
        qs = Category.objects.filter(menu__id=instance.id)
        data = CategorySerializer(qs,many=True).data
        return data

    class Meta:
        model  = Menu
        fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
item_instance = Item.objects.filter(is_active = True, category__is_active=True)
```

you will get all active items that have an active category using this.

fetch all items and create JSON data from them.

upvote if it helps

Comment: Hey harshil, your anwser is not correct, cause this way you only filter menus.